# Jupyter notebook won't open

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Jupyter notebook on the Anaconda can not be open

The terminal
[image]

It did not work when I ran it as an admin.

It also did not work after downloading anaconda again

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, click on the http://localhost link or copy paste it in your browser, this should open the notebook